# Sending object with params in the get method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this get method that receives this filter parameter, which is an object with from and I want to pass them as parameters inside the url

```
export async function queryEventTimelineFilteredAPI(filter) {
  
  console.log('componentManager', filter)

  
  const response = await fetch('/api/v1/data/queryEventTimeline', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  })
  return await response.json();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify()` to convert it to JSON, `encodeURIComponent()` to add proper `%` encoding of special characters, and then concatenate it to the URL.

There's no need for the `Content-type` header, since GET requests have no content.

```js
export async function queryEventTimelineFilteredAPI(filter) {
  
  console.log('componentManager', filter)

  const response = await fetch('/api/v1/data/queryEventTimeline?filter=' +  encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(filter)), {
    method: 'GET',
  })
  return await response.json();
}
```

Note that URL length is generally pretty limited, so the JSON filter should not be large. It would be better to send it as POST data.

Comment: Well it now transforms the url into an object, but in my api the get method
I'll have to reuse this url to look it up in the BD

app.get('/api/v1/data/queryEventTimeline?filter=', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('query event timeline')
    console.log(req.params)
    const dbres = await statistics.QueryEventTimeline()
    res.json(dbres)

  }) 

like this?

Comment: In the API you'll need to use `JSON.parse(req.params.filter)` to decode the query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this jQuery function: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/